# How can I remove duplication of routes nested in different scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got same routes inside namespace and subdomain constraint.

First is used on production, second in development. How can remove this duplication?

```
constraints :subdomain => 'api' do
    scope :module => "api" do
      resources :users
      resources :orders
    end     
end

namespace :api do
    resources :users
    resources :orders
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `do ... end` creates a block. If you have a block that's repeated you can instead save it to a variable by turning it into a Proc, by passing it to `Proc.new` or `proc` (the latter is just a shortcut for the former):

```
res = Proc.new do
  resources :users
  resources :orders
end
```

Then you can pass the Proc (`res`) as a block argument to any method that expects a block by prepending it with `&`:

```
constraints :subdomain => 'api' do
  scope :module => 'api', &res
end

namespace :api, &res
```

[Here's a great article](http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/) on using blocks, Procs, and lambdas in Ruby.